# Paging in Facebook API Taggable Friends Endpoint

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I noticed that when you use the taggable_friends endpoint on the Facebook API you get dumped what looks like all your friends. At the bottom it has an array:

```
 [paging] => Array
        (
            [cursors] => Array
                (
                    [before] => QWFLa3MyVFBjQnQ2Y0hiTGVlMFR0QzFpeWFSNTRDNXHNMUHlhN1NqdzZrMU85enFHQUw4YjQtRF9FV2RrbHROcER3c3ljLTNuajdJRm1uX3c=
                    [after] => QWFJUDdOVS1YYmMwVjJObGlRY0FVeW4zemoyVGnaEd3bTJFZ3E2Q0hjVkhkREtuc2VIQ1p2MWhWZnRmblpXU2x2RS15LUFjdl9hQWlzQ1pFcUVkTXc=
                )

        )
```

However, there doesn't look to be anything to use these cursors with. Is this an unfinished pagination feature or am i missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those are paging cursors, documented here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/using-graph-api/v2.1#paging

Specifically:

`before` : This is the cursor that points to the start of the page of data that has been returned.

`after` : This is the cursor that points to the end of the page of data that has been returned.

You can use the 'after' cursor to make a second request and see only the records added after that, subject to the restriction that if the 'after' record itself was deleted, the request will fail.

If there's no 'next'/'previous' links returned, it's probably because there are no records not in the result set you retrieved

Comment: do you happen to know how many users the taggable_friends endpoint will return before it starts paging? I can't seem to find any information on after what number the paging starts.

Comment: No, i'm not sure, sorry - you should probably write code to assume paging will be needed to get all results, though